StringReplace with several replacement rules doesn't work as expected
I understand that, according to WL documentation, StringReplace["16.",{aux:NumberString:>"1/"<>aux,".":>"*3/2"}] should produce "1/16*3/2" but instead it produces "1/16.".
If programmed with two StringReplace:
StringReplace[StringReplace["16.",aux:NumberString:>"1/"<>aux],".":>"*3/2"]
it produces the right answer: "1/16*3/2".
What's wrong with the first approach?
Thankyou!!!

Perhapss depends on versions. Is working with vs13.

NumberString Will match "16.". Therefore, there is nothing left to match ".".

@Danielhuber you have got it. Thank you very much. If I change "." period character with another character, i.e. "·" it works ok!!!

There are at least two ways: you either define the pattern in a single rule, or you use both rules and apply them sequentially using Fold.
First Case: The pattern in a single rule.
StringReplace["16.", x : NumberString ~~ "." :> "1/" <> x <> "*3/2"]


1/16*3/2

Second Case: Using two rules and applying them sequentially.
Fold[StringReplace, "16.", {x : NumberString :> "1/" <> x, "." :> "*3/2"}]


1/16*3/2

In your first approach, the way you define the pattern for your rule is incorrect.
